# How do Linux PIDS increment

Tags: process, systemd

Why do PIDS under Linux (generally) increment by 4? The only exception I can think of is startup processes run by systemd, which increment by 1 when they are related or 2 otherwise.

How was the number 4 chosen as the default, and is it changeable?

Comment: What makes you believe that PIDs were incremented by 4?

Comment: Run anything on your system, say `ps -e`. The PID of `ps -e` will be 4 greater than whatever the last started process was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PIDs are increased by one.

Start two shells.

**shell 1**

```
echo $$
# we assume 1234 as output
```

**shell 2**

```
strace -f -p 1234 -e trace=clone
```

**shell 1**

```
sleep 1 ; sleep 1
```

**shell 2**

```
# output like
clone(Process 25484 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4111a029d0) = 25484
[pid 25484] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=25484,si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(Process 25485 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4111a029d0) = 25485
[pid 25485] +++ exited with 0 +++
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=25485,     si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(Process 25486 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD,child_tidptr=0x7f4111a029d0) = 25486
[pid 25486] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 3):

PIDs increment by one except specific patches like `gr-security`. If you see an increment by steps of 4, this is probably due to your shell executing some extra commands everytime, for example through the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

Comment: Mine are incrementing by 2 in bash: if I do a series of `ps`. When I look into it I see that `cd_prompt` is starting one process (it calculates the window title), every time the prompt is returned.